Access to Forecasting related objects
Recently I was asked to provide the access to one field which is Access Level which is on Forecasting share standard object.
This standard object and other related forecasting object I can't see in the profile to give access.
He (the user from business) mentioned that he can see this object in heroku but not in Salesforce.
Could anyone tell how access to forecasting objects works like forecasting Item, forecasting share, etc and how I can provide access to him?
Thank you for the help!
